# Concerning Constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am completely new to sql (have couple of days to get to know it) and have following question:

Here is a syntax for constraints:

While creating the table, I have this kind of line:

```
CONSTRAINT smth UNIQUE(name)
```

I understand that it puts constraint on column `name` for it to be unique but what is `smth` for? Why do we need to name the constraint? Is it used anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You name it (as with many things) so that you can perform *maintenance* in your database easily.

See [ALTER TABLE ... DROP CONSTRAINT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html) and note that you have to supply the *name* of the constraint there.

Also, it's helpful if the constraint is [*violated*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html):

> An optional name for a column or table constraint. If the constraint is violated, the constraint name is present in error messages, so constraint names like col must be positive can be used to communicate helpful constraint information to client applications.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints have names.

It is useful. Just imagine:

- when you need to drop a constraint
- when you list constraints on a object
- when a constraint fails, it will show name in error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE(column_name)
```

column_name: to which you are applying constraint

constraint_name: name of the constraint, which you are applying to column_name

It is used to identify the UNIQUE(present declared) constraint and can able to delete if not needed